# Are Elementals and other extraplanar creatures "Alive"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

Recently I've been reading up on the Pathfinder Slayer, and the Blood Reader talent fascinates me. It states that I can determine the remaining hit points of any living enemy, but it does not work on creatures that are not alive. Now, enemies such as Elementals who lack organs, do not bleed, and sometimes even lack a tangible form. They lack all of the hallmarks of life, except for mobility. So, in general, are Elementals and other extraplanars considered living creatures for Pathfinder?

Comment: Closely related: [What being a *living creature* means in *Pathfinder* and *3.5e*.](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51349/8610)

Comment: Do you really want answers for every edition all the way back to white box D&D or do you really mean "Pathfinder and D&D 3.x"?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Removed the DnD tag and question for clarification

Comment: [Blood Biography](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blood-biography) is a spell - did you perhaps mean the Slayer's talent [Blood Reader](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/slayer/slayer-talents/paizo---slayer-talents/blood-reader)? The spell won't work on elementals as it explicitly targets "one creature's blood or one bloodstain" - the talent should work on them as it simply targets 'living creatures' - the mention of blood in its name is just a cooler sounding title...

Comment: @G0BLiN Blood reader is correct, I edited it so the correct ability is shown.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they are alive.

Generally speaking everything that has a constitution score is considered "alive", unless otherwise noted. It is also confirmed by the [outsider creature type description](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Outsider), and [a previous answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/51355/31843).

> Unlike most living creatures, an outsider does not have a dual nature

There are, in general, only two creature types that are considered non-living: [Constructs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Construct) and [undead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Undead).

PS: Other systems may have differences on this, as my answer is based upon  Pathfinder and D&D 3.x